# How to send more than 10^15 of an ERC20 token using the truffle console?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-console

I am trying to test my contract but everytime I try to send more than 10^15 I get an overflow error while I know my wallet can send more than that. Any solutions?

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract NGE is ERC20 {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => bool) public haveAccess;
    constructor() ERC20("Neon", "NGE") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000*10**16);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function giveAccess(address to) public returns(bool){
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only the owner can give access to this contract");
        haveAccess[msg.sender] = true;
        return(true);
    }

    function minter(address to, uint256 amount) public{
        require(msg.sender == owner || haveAccess[msg.sender] == true);
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

^ token contract code.

```
truffle(bscTestnet)> token.approve('0xB8b7E4982b71828Dc1FF9b7e3548CdfFaAD6Afbd', 10**16)
Uncaught:
Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=10000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:7
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:273:12)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:142:14)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:270:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:285:1)
    at bound (domain.js:421:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:432:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:909:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:434:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:791:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1136:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:1004:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:265:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at ReadStream.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline/utils.js:358:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:1270:36) {
  reason: 'overflow',
  code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
  fault: 'overflow',
  operation: 'BigNumber.from',
  value: 10000000000000000,
  hijackedStack: 'Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=10000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)\n' +
    '    at Logger.makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:166:1)\n' +
    '    at Logger.throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:175:1)\n' +
    '    at throwFault (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib.esm/bignumber.js:273:1)\n' +
    '    at Function.from (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib.esm/bignumber.js:178:1)\n' +
    '    at NumberCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/number.js:13:17)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:41:1\n' +
    '    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at pack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:27:1)\n' +
    '    at TupleCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/tuple.js:19:16)\n' +
    '    at AbiCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js:82:1)\n' +
    '    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:145:1)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:531:1\n' +
    '    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:530:10)\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:181:1\n' +
    '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)'
}
```

^error message and original command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dealing with truffle console for transactions purposes use string values like address values, because of number is too large for JavaScript to handle. This issue is discussed at [openzeppelin](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/mytoken-sol-mint-javascript-error-overflow-on-big-numbers/4991) forum.

instead of:

```
token.approve('0xB8b7E4982b71828Dc1FF9b7e3548CdfFaAD6Afbd', 10**16)
```

use:

```
token.approve('0xB8b7E4982b71828Dc1FF9b7e3548CdfFaAD6Afbd', '100000000000000000')
```

Comment: Or use the more readable form : '1'+'0'.repeat(16) or a const gwei variable in bignumber : const GWEI = BN.from('10').pow('18'); that you then multiply/divide as needed, in BN : const ten_ethers = GWEI.mul(10)